# 2004 Ford Ranger heater stopped working after repair

Tags: ford, ac, heater, ranger

I had my AC repaired by the Ford dealer.  They said they investigated the whole system and only found it was low on refrigerant so they recharged it and everything was great... Except now my heater doesn't work.   I thought that seemed suspicious.  They say the blend door motor is bad & needs to be replaced.  Could there be any relationship between their previous work on the AC and this new problem?

Comment: Was the heat working before?

Comment: Yes.  If it didn't work before, it would not have seemed suspicious that it didn't work after.  To be clear: The heater worked before the A/C repair.  It didn't work after the A/C repair.  The shop said there was no relationship between the A/C repair and the fact that the heater didn't work afterward.  They charged me $402.00 to replaced the blend door motor.

Comment: That seems odd. Can anybody think of a scenario where the blend door would be in a position where there would be heat with the a/c not working but then only cold after the a/c repair?